# About key and address difference between Quorum and Ethereum blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

Quorum is a fork of Ethereum, what are the main difference of them about private key/public key/address generation and representation format?
In the link [Quorum wiki](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/constellation), there is a public key like below:

```
{"payload": "foo", "from": "mypublickey", to: "ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="}
```

the public key above is different format from ethereum HEX public key.What's it and its encoding format?

Meanwhile, I also noticed in the link [Quorum example](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/README.md), the block info printed is all the same with ethereum:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x4d6eb0d0f971b5e0394a49e36ba660c69e62a588323a873bb38610f7b9690b34",
  blockNumber: 1,
  from: "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d",
  gas: 4700000,
  gasPrice: 0,
  hash: "0xe28912c5694a1b8c4944b2252d5af21724e9f9095daab47bac37b1db0340e0bf",
  input: "0x58c0c680ee0b55673e3127eb26e5e537c973cd97c70ec224ccca586cc4d31ae042d2c55704b881d26ca013f15ade30df2dd196da44368b4a7abfec4a2022ec6f",
  nonce: 0,
  r: "0x4952fd6cd1350c283e9abea95a2377ce24a4540abbbf46b2d7a542be6ed7cce5",
  s: "0x4596f7afe2bd23135fa373399790f2d981a9bb8b06144c91f339be1c31ec5aeb",
  to: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x25",
  value: 0
}
```

How to understand the above info?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Quorum adds a number of features into plain Ethereum, tho from perspective of using it or developing a dapp with it its practically the same. These features are what make Quorum enterprise ready and they are: privacy (as in peer to peer privacy through private smart contracts), permissioning (as in ability to set up the entire chain's nodes), pluggable consensus algo (theres a choice between Istanbul BFT or Raft and either provides 100s of txns/sec) and finaly, txn and bloxk finality.

A regular txn in Quorum is exactly the same as in plain Ethereum and it creates a public txn. If you execute the same txn but add `privateFor` then the txn is intended to the recipients defined in the `privateFor` array and its payload will only be sent to the intended recipients. Quorum node is responsible for replacing the payload with a hash of the encrypted txn via talking to its Private Transaction Manager (which transfers the actual payload to the private recipients) and writes out a public txn with a new `v` value and payload of the transfered secret hash.

The keys Private Transaction Manager uses are explained in detail here: http://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Privacy/Tessera/Configuration/Keys/ but essentially, they are a pre-generated public/private set controlled by the node operator and secured with argon2 and nacl libraries.

Comment: At first,With 'privateFor' function, if a transaction is sent to three recipients, does it mean that there will be three seperate transactions processed by Ethereum and Quorum is just to add easy-using call interface? Seconedly, when signing a transaction, does quorum node use its private key to sign txn instead of using ethereum private key? why is there a new v value?

Comment: For the first part of the question: only a single txn is recorded on the blockchain, but the private transaction manager sends payload to all the recipients separately. For signing a txn: this depends where your Ethereum accounts key is. If its node managed, then you sign / send with the node, if its externally managed, then you may use our quorum.js library to sign externally: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum.js

This page provides detailed explanation of what happens: http://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Privacy/Tessera/How%20Tessera%20Works/.